# Using Twitter API to get images tweeted by a user (REST API)

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest, twitter

I'm using the Twitter REST API to try and get only images for a specific user.

If I use `statuses/user_timeline`, then I get a mixture of of textual tweets and images, and the results are limited to 200. This means that I can end up with about 10 images per 200 results, because of the text tweets involved in the returned data.

What I'm trying to do instead, is use `tweets/search` with the `From:Username filter:images` keywords. But I have encountered an issue: On twitter.com, the search term `From:Gregory_Onye filter:images` returns a few results, but when using the API I receive only 1 result...

Can anyone help me with this issue?

See below for search metadata:

```
"search_metadata":  {
    "completed_in": 0.03,
    "max_id": 579641668875452400,
    "max_id_str": "579641668875452416",
    "query": "From%3AGregory_Onye+filter%3Aimages",
    "refresh_url": "?since_id=579641668875452416&q=From%3AGregory_Onye%20filter%3Aimages&include_entities=1",
    "count": 100,
    "since_id": 0,
    "since_id_str": "0"
  }
```